# UiTableViewCell Dynamic height works on iphone not ipad size class

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

So basically I have the any any size class that I am using for iPhone and the regular regular for iPad. With that being said I have a custom `UITableViewCell` and I have the cell auto sizing for iPhone. I laid out the constraints vertically to help it know what size the cell should be.

The problem is on the iPad size class I am doing the same thing, obviously the layout is a little different but I checked every element and it has a top and bottom and height constraint on it yet the `UITableViewCell` is as high as the iPhone layout.

Here is my code for that scene:

```
import UIKit

class TruckListMainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var truckNames = ["This Truck Test"]
var truckImages = ["default-truck.png"]
var oneAverages = ["5.02"]
var twoAverages = ["6.02"]
var threeAverages = ["7.02"]
var fourAverages = ["8.02"]
var oneLabels = ["30 Day MPG"]
var twoLabels = ["60 Day MPG"]
var threeLabels = ["90 Day MPG"]
var fourLabels = ["Lifetime MPG"]

@IBOutlet weak var truckListTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var openMenu: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.truckListTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.truckListTable.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0

    openMenu.target = self.revealViewController()
    openMenu.action = Selector("rightRevealToggle:")

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return truckNames.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! truckList

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.truckName.text = truckNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.truckImage.image = UIImage(named: truckImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.averageOne.setTitle(oneAverages[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.averageTwo.setTitle(twoAverages[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.averageOne.setTitle(threeAverages[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.averageOne.setTitle(fourAverages[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.labelOne.setTitle(oneLabels[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.labelTwo.setTitle(twoLabels[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.labelThree.setTitle(threeLabels[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.labelFour.setTitle(fourLabels[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 202/255.0, green: 202/255.0, blue: 202/255.0, alpha: 1)
    } else {

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255.0, green: 240/255.0, blue: 240/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }
}




/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I wouldnt post on here but I have been struggling with this issue for almost 2 days now. If I could post pictures I would, I know it would help to see the constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked every element and it has a top and bottom and height constraint on it yet the UITableViewCell is as high as the iPhone layout

You may be confused about how cell heights are determined. If you don't want the cell height determined by internal constraints, you need to set the table view's `rowHeight` property to some actual number (*not* `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`).

Comment: Ya I must be confused. I thought if you had a string of vertical constraints and heights that the cell would determine its own height. That is what Im trying to do, am I wrong about that?

Comment: I used this: `if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad{
            self.truckListTable.rowHeight = 200.0
        }else{
            self.truckListTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            self.truckListTable.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
        }` But would love to do this based off of constraints and not set a height for ipads.

Comment: I figured it out, I had those two lines in there the whole time and when I read your answer a couple times it dawned on me that I was doing both. I deleted those two lines and things are working great now, thanks!